# Adding arrays output

Tags: java, arrays

I'd need some help with this. I'm new to java and this is my task:

I have to write code that has an integer array in it. A pair of the arrays values have to be `=42`. Then I have to output the pair through normal `System.out.println`.

This is the code I've got so far. Maybe I even got this completely wrong.
My problem is getting the program to correctly output what the pairs are that are `=42`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = { 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 6, 5, 39, 40, 34 };
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++)
               if (array[i] + array[k] == 42)
                   System.out.println("Found pairs at");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with your code?

Comment: Welcome to SO! to get the most help please share what have you tried , show example input & output for the desirable solution and what problem have you encounter

Comment: i have tried to make an output that says something like "2 and 40 equals 42"

Comment: Basically I want it to be able to show which numbers of the array equal 42

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there :) You can build the output string simply by using the `+` operator:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {2,3,5,6,8,6,5,39,40,34};

        for (int  i=0; i< array.length  ; i++) {
            for (int k=0; k< array.length; k++) {
                if (array[i] + array[k] == 42)
                    System.out.println("Found pairs at " + i + " " + k + ": " + array[i] + " and " + array[k] + " equals 42");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the format function, which is probably easier to read:

```
System.out.format("Found pairs at %d %d : %d and %d equals 42", i, k, array[i], array[k]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int[] array = {2,3,5,6,8,6,5,39,40,34};
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        for (int k=0; k<array.length; k++)
           if (i != k && array[i] + array[k] == 42)
               System.out.println("Found pairs at " + i + " and " + k + ".");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Found pairs at 0 and 8.
Found pairs at 1 and 7.
Found pairs at 4 and 9.
Found pairs at 7 and 1.
Found pairs at 8 and 0.
Found pairs at 9 and 4.
```

See a live [**demo**](https://ideone.com/uMmhYA).

---

**Edit**: I have added `i!=k` in the `if` condition because you are looking for two numbers in the array that sum to 42. So, if the number `21` appears in the input array, your program will give you the index of number `21` twice when `i=k` since you are checking `array[i] + array[k] == 42`.

Comment: Can you explain that condition? I think that helps OP more than just the code.